# Php numberformatter displaying zero

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm trying to display currency in invoice in words. Why is $total value displaying as zero / zero / zero ?

```
    <td class="no-borders" colspan="2">
            <table class="totals">
                <tfoot>
                    <?php foreach( $this->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) : ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <td class="no-borders"></td>

                        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>

                        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>

                        <?php $f = new NumberFormatter("lv", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
                        echo $f->format($total['value']); ?>

                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What is the value of $total['value'] then if not zero?

Comment: your locale code have to be "lv-LV", and have to be present on your system.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: @Andreas When i <?php echo $total['value'] ?> it comes out as €20.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numberformatter wants numbers not strings.

`20` is a number. `€20` is a string.

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format("20.00");  // twenty or divdesmit in lv
echo "\n";
echo $f->format("€20.00");  // zero or nulle in lv
echo "\n";
echo $f->format(str_replace("€", "", "€20.00")); // str_replace to remove euro sign
```

https://3v4l.org/eA6u9

Comment: Is there a way to convert the value to int so the € sign gets ignored?
<?php $int = (int)$total['value']; ?>

Comment: str_replace still saves the euro sign, might be cause its as currency not string?

Comment: How can it be a currency? As far as I know there is no data type called currency. You have string, integer, float, bool and so on

Comment: Can you copy paste the code you use? The line with str_replace and (if not the same) the line with the echo of numberformatter. Also just to be sure can you `var_dump($total['value']);` and copy the output to me? It should say what data type "value" is. @Kara

Comment: var_dumb comes out as string(118) "€20.00". I'm basically trying to add spellout form for currency ( wordpress plugin woocomerce ).
@Andreas
The code of the first file:
https://3v4l.org/Lhf8G

Comment: String(118) says it's a string with 118 characters. That means it's not as you have said earlier `€20.00`. Let's try again. What is the value of $total['value']?

Comment: Well to be honest i have no clue how does $total['value'] gets the String like that, but when you `echo out the $total['value'] ` it comes out as "€20.00 ". The $total['value'] = Complete order price. Tried to find a function about value but couldn't really find it. It's this plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/) **\templates\Simple\invoice.php**. Well i'll keep looking and keep you updated if i come across something. @Andreas Thanks for the help tho, appreciate it.